# Memory Cache not working in .Net Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache, objectcache

My project is built on .Net Framework 4.0 and we are using built in `ObjectCache` as `MemoryCache` which is implemented in `System.Runtime.Caching`.

It was working fine previously but suddenly it has stopped saving anything on the cache. When I call `Set` method on cache it doesn't save anything and the `Result View` is always empty, stating `Enumeration yielded no results`. I double checked the code and found no catch there. It's really as simple as something like below:

```
var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
cache = new MemoryCache("MyCache");
cache.Set("item", "item value", policy);
var item = cache.Get("item");
cache.Remove("item"); //when removal is required
```

However, a sample application targeting .Net Framework 4 on the same machine works. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced similar behavior and how could I get to the core of this issue? Is there any tool out there to help?

Comment: If you change the name of the `MemoryCache` to something else, does it start working again?

Comment: What does your Result view refer to, where are you assigning it to the Get value fetched, no where in this code. Are you getting `item` as null. Also what's `CacheItemPolicy`

Comment: @FrankerZ Cache instance is registered in Container and passed around. Strangely when I registered the cache with new name. The one resolved is still getting "Default" named cache. I need to check from where is it getting that cache.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I'm referring to `Result View` that we can see while debugging. Its empty right after setting an item to cache. If I call `cache.GetCount()` i get 0. `CacheItemPolicy` is initialized to its default.

Comment: Even below three consecutive lines of code is not working in my project. 
`Cache = new MemoryCache("MyCache"); 
            CachingPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            Cache.Set("item", "value", CachingPolicy);`
It assigns "Default" name to cache and doesn't set the value. Probably an internal bug in assembly or framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of error. I was disposing container that had container controlled  instance of Cache. When container was disposing, it was also disposing my cache. And it was unable to Set values on a disposed cache object. It should have thrown exception but it didn't, hence the whole confusion. Future readers please be aware.

```
var CachingPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
var Cache = new MemoryCache("YourCacheName");
container.RegisterInstance(CachingPolicy);
container.RegisterInstance(Cache);

container.Dispose(); //disposes cache as well. But calling methods on cache object won't throw exception.

//at this point, you should create the cache again, like
CachingPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
Cache = new MemoryCache("YourCacheName");
container.RegisterInstance(CachingPolicy);
container.RegisterInstance(Cache);
```

Further digging in `MemoryCache` code through ILSpy cleared that, it doesn't set anything if the object is disposed.

```
if (IsDisposed)
{
    if (collection != null)
    {
        foreach (ChangeMonitor item in collection)
        {
            item?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MemoryCacheKey memoryCacheKey = new MemoryCacheKey(key);
    MemoryCacheStore store = GetStore(memoryCacheKey);
    store.Set(memoryCacheKey, new MemoryCacheEntry(key, value, absExp, slidingExp, priority, collection, removedCallback, this));
}
```

Comment: Which container is this ? Docker or Dependency Injection ?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj its Unity DI container.

Comment: Then you have posted half information, anything that's disposed is anyway never a valid object, this has nothing to do with cache and why would you even dispose cache during initialization

Comment: I wasn't sure that lifetime of my cache was as of container. I'd have thrown `ObjectDisposedException` on `Set` method of cache to at least inform caller that the object is disposed. Also, I'm disposing container to load services on user's token during log in. Hope its clear now.